# Temporizador em Python

Tags: python

Estou a tentar fazer um temporizador que passados 10 segundos imprima uma *string*.

Tentei usar o `time.sleep()` e não resultou.

Exemplo:

```
def tempo():
    #passados 10 segundos
    print "olá"
```

Comment: Eu fiz um jeito bem melhor: from time import sleep def espere(tempo): sleep(tempo)

Comment: E como é que isso ajuda a resolver o problema que está na pergunta? Onde é que o `print("olá")` seria usado com isso? Qual é a razão que levaria alguém a usar a sua função `espere` ao invés de usar `sleep` diretamente?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use o método [`time.sleep()`](https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/time.html#time.sleep).

```
import time

def tempo():
    time.sleep(10)    
    print "Ola"
```

Para fazer um cronômetro e imprimir o número na mesma linha:

```
import time, sys

for i in range(0, 10):
    sys.stdout.write("\r{}".format(i))
    sys.stdout.flush()
    time.sleep(1)

print ("\nFim")
```

[Ver `demonstração`](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/execute_python_online.php?PID=0Bw_CjBb95KQMaEV5TGNYWFRUVlk)

Comment: Obrigado ;) Provavelmente esqueci-me de fazer import time.

Comment: E é possível fazer um cronómetro, isto é, contar o tempo numa única linha?

Comment: mas que a contagem substituisse o número que está lá antes:

Comment: Mas continua a adicionar numeros na contagem

Answer (score -2):

Acho que uma forma mais reduzida, seria:

```
from  time import sleep 

for contagem in range(0,10):
    sleep(1)

print('Olá!')
```

Comment: Não entendi porque chamar `sleep` 10x seria mais "reduzido" que chamar apenas uma.

Answer (score -4):

From time import sleep

Msg = str(imput("digite uma frase:"))
Vezes = int(imput("quantas vezes deseja a execução dessa frase:")

While Vezes:

```
Print(Msg)

Sleep(10)
```

print("fim da execução")

Comment: Cuidado. A função `imput` não existe no Python, a correta é `input`; o retorno dela sempre é uma string, então chamar `str` é inserir redundância no código; como você não modifica o valor de `Vezes`, se for digitado qualquer valor diferente de 0 causará um loop infinito; `From` deveria ser `from`; `While` deveria ser `while`, `Print` deveria ser `print`; `Sleep` deveria ser `sleep`